# Python 2.7.12 + dev_appserver.py does not suports java8

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

I'm trying to run an appengine module with the command below:

- $ python /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --max_module_instances = 1 --jvm_flag = "- agentlib: jdwp = transport = dt_socket, server = y, suspend = n, address = 9999 "target / security-authentication-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT --dev_appserver_log_level = debug

But I'm getting this error:

- DEBUG 2018-02-22 14: 15: 27,450 appengine_rpc.py:170] Server: appengine.google.com
- ERROR 2018-02-22 14: 15: 27,452 sdk_update_checker.py:201] The requested api_version (1.0) is not supported by the java8 runtime in this release of the SDK. The supported api_versions are ['1'].

How do I solve this problem?

Here is some information:
$ gcloud -v

- Google Cloud SDK 190.0.0
- alpha 2017.12.08
- app-engine-java 1.9.62
- app-engine-python 1.9.67
- beta 2017.12.08
- bq 2.0.29
- core 2018.02.16
- gsutil 4.28

$ python --version

- Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests you may have used an `api_version` other than `1`. From the `api_version` row in the [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#syntax) table:

> At this time, App Engine has one version of the python27 runtime
>   environment: 1

Make sure you have this in your `app.yaml`, not something else:

```
api_version: 1
```

You also have both the Python and Java development tools installed in your SDK and using some arguments which are specific to the Java development server, that *might* not work (well) with the Python development server you're attempting to invoke. See the Python [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) and [Local Development Server Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command) vs [Using the Java Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server).